# Angular select keeps generating default missing option

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, ag-grid

I have a `select` being rendered inside of an `agGrid`. Nothing exceptionally complicated.

```
<select ng-model="data.stdPayerClassFnbr" ng-change="vm.save(data)" style="width: 100%"
        ng-options="item.stdPayerClass for item in vm.payerClassList track by item.id">
</select>
```

The crazy thing is this; I keep getting the missing value option:

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
```

Even though the value of `data.stdPayerClassFnbr` exists in the list of rendered options:

```
<option value="1" label="TBD">TBD</option>
```

The underlying data type of both `data.stdPayerClassFnbr` and `item.id` is `int`; however I've tried making them both `string` by executing a `map` against their values before binding them. That did not help. I've got to be configuring this `select` wrong.

I've also tried the `ng-repeat` approach:

```
<select ng-model="data.stdPayerClassFnbr" ng-change="vm.save(data)" style="width: 100%">
    <option ng-repeat="item in vm.payerClassList" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.stdPayerClass}}</option>
</select>
```

This did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `stdPayerClassFnbr` model object has the same properties as the `payerClassList[x]` items. Especially properties `id` and `stdPayerClass`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was the `track by` expression. Since I was binding to an array of objects that came back from a lookup, when selecting or looking for a value, it was looking for the entire object by reference. Removing the `track by` expression caused the binding to work directly on the numeric value:

```
<select ng-model="data.stdPayerClassFnbr" ng-change="vm.save(data)" style="width: 100%"
        ng-options="item.id as item.stdPayerClass for item in vm.payerClassList">
</select>
```

This generates a very different list of options:

```
<option value="number:1" label="TBD" selected="selected">TBD</option>
```

I hope this helps somebody in the future! It may even help me one day!